# Prevent WebBrowser Control from automatically adding <A> Tag when contentEditable is set

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I use `WebBrowser` control and have text inside like:

```
some text https://www.example.com some text.
```

This is my code the way I added the text and enabled the web browser to edit contents:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private HTMLBody _body;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        _body = ((HTMLBody)((HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument).body);
        _body.contentEditable = true.ToString();
        _body.innerHTML = "some text https://www.example.com some text";
    }
}
```

If I run it and changed part of link (for type something else instead of 'example.com' and lost focus) then it automatically adds tag `<a>` around my link. You can see it in innerHTML property. But it's wrong for me.

Is there a way to avoid to do this behavior?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you change the text? Such question needs some code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I set contentEditable = true and use this control like usual textbox

Comment: No problem, post a really simple code to reproduce the problem. At the first step it will help you to find the problem yourself and if you didn't find the problem yourself, it helps other users to understand your question and the situation correctly and lets them to help you by reproducing the problem simply at their programming environment without extra efforts which may be different than what you are looking for. The question seems to be good, but to make it more useful Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off auto-dettecting url in document. To do so, in `DocumentCompleted` evnet after you set the new content for body, add this line of code:

```
webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("AutoUrlDetect", false, false);
```

Also you can make the content editable without adding reference to `mshtml.dll`. To do so you can simply use:

```
this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"<HTML><BODY contentEditable=""true""></BODY></HTML>";
```